# Trigger event on aspx page from .cs file without stopping current execution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page which posts a form back to itself, processes the form in a .cs page (in the DLL, not code behind) and then the code takes one of many branches based on that outcome.

This is a rough outline of what happens:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LoanApplication oLoanApplication = new LoanApplication();
string sStep  = Request.Form["step"];
oLoanApplication.Process(Request.Form); //Sets the value of the object
}
```

Then, in the `Process` method that is in the DLL code, I want it to trigger an event at this point:

```
public void Process(NameValueCollection pFormData)
{
 SendApplicationToWebService();
//Trigger event here on aspx page
}
```

Basically I am trying to pass a variable returned from the `SendApplicationToWebService();` into Google Tag manager.

There are many different branches the code could take, and I do not think it is a good solution to do it at the end - it is best to do it at the point the variable is assigned its value - that way I know all code is passing through this point.

Some of the branches redirect to different pages, so I cannot do this after the `process` method is called on the `Page_Load` because the code may never be executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass a callback function to `oLoanApplication.Process` ?

take a look on this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931723/passing-a-callback-function-to-another-class)